# Voltage, Current, Wattage and Power Outlets

Tags: power-supply

A few years ago I plugged in 2 space heaters into 2 outlets on the same receptacle.

The power went out. Is there a simple calculation so that I have a general sense of how much current is drawn from the devices and how much is available from the outlets?

Comment: In the US, with only 120 VAC per split phase, older installations will find 15 A as a common allowance for the entire circuit that a breaker at the panel covers. (20 A is becoming a new standard I'm seeing, though.) A mobile space heater, regardless of physical size, is supposed to live within that budget -- and are typically about 12.5 A to make allowances for small items on the same circuit. But in no conceivable way can you put two of them together on such a typical circuit. So where are you located and why didn't you let us know the current rating on the breaker you had to reset?

Comment: Breakers trip on overcurrent, measured in amps. Amps = Watts/Volts.  (I = P/V) .For V = 110V then 1100 W gives 10A.  For 230 V 2300 W = 10A. So: Look at breaker current rating (I).  May power Vmains x I = eg 110 V x 10 A = 1100 W. Look at rating plates on heaters. Add the watts. Do these exced the breaker rating?

Comment: THIS IS A LEGITIMATE QUESTION. Yes, it's a bout comsumer equipment. Its also about breaper rating, current draw, ... .

Answer (score 0):

The calculations are simple, but not knowing the wiring and circuit breaker configuration is what makes it a bit tricky. A layman might not be aware of how the house is wired.

Typically, there will be mains circuit breakers (MCBs) on all lines. Let's assume the electrician used a 30 amp MCB on the high-current wiring loop. Now, this loop might get exposed at 5 places (sockets/receptacles) and each receptacle is rated for 10 amps. In such a case, you can fully load 3 of these receptacles simultaneously but not all 5.

You need to have an understanding of MCB and what all load is connected on those lines before you connect a new appliance on those lines.

As far as the calculation is concerned, you should not be drawing more current than rated from any MCB or any receptacle and you will be good.